# Python regex boundary

Tags: python, regex

Is there an error in the way python handles '.' or '\b'? I'm not sure why this produces differing results.

```
import re

regex1 = r'\.?\b'
print bool(re.match(regex1, '.'))

regex2 = r'a?\b'
print bool(re.match(regex2, 'a'))
```

Output:

```
False

True
```

Answer (score 4):

`\b`, word boundary, matches between word characters and non-word elements.  As such, it will match between a word character like `a` and the end of the string, but not between a non-word character like `.` and end of string.

Answer (score 0):

As geekosaur pointed out `\b` is merely a short way of writing

```
(?:(?<=\w)(?!\w)|(?<!\w)(?=\w))
```

In your case you may want to use

```
(?!\w)
```

or

```
(?!\S)
```

instead of `\b`.